# Is $Recycle.Bin a Windows directory?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

I have the folder `$Recycle.Bin` on my hard drive's root directory. The drive used to be used with Windows, now only with Linux. Can Unix systems ever create this directory?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this folder is specific to Windows.
But there is no telling if none of the 500+ Linux distros in the world have ever used this. I haven't tried them all and I highly doubt anyone else has either.

What puzzles me is why the folder is there?
Didn't you format the partition before installing Linux on it?
If you didn't the root filesystem is still FAT or NTFS and neither is a good choice for Linux as root filesystem. (As a data-only filesystem its OK, but not as a system filesystem.)

Comment: This is an external HDD which is still NTFS-formatted. I'm clearing redundant data before backing up and then reformatting the drive.

Comment: @user598527 I see. I mistook root-folder (of the drive) for root-filesystem. Now it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly a remnant of the old windows install on the drive.

The $Recycle.Bin folder mentioned here is in almost every folder within a normal windows system, just hidden and out of sight. i think coincidentally an effect from moving the drive from windows to a linux based distro has uncovered this file from being hidden.

there should be no consequence of deleting said file.